# Could not find property 'keyStorePath' on project ':app' in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a task in app module build.gradle

```
task testKeyStorePath << {
    println "what, " + keyStorePath
    File file = file(keyStorePath)
    println file.isFile()
}
```

In ~/.bash_profile

```
#Key store path
export ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_keyStorePath=/Users/Marshall/Documents/eclipse.keystore
```

**I'm sure that it is correctly set**

In Android Studio, Gradle sync fail

```
Error:(16, 0) Could not find property 'keyStorePath' on project ':app'.
```

But, in Terminal

```
 ./gradlew testKeyStorePath -q
 what, /Users/Marshall/Documents/eclipse.keystore
 true
```

Why?

Comment: I guess that this is a problem with Android Studio itself. It does not ready the system's environment variables.

Comment: did you try rebooting or logging in and out? Usually .bash_profile is loaded during whole session start. Also I'm not sure if it is always respected on MacOS (maybe it is only for Terminal sessions, not for the whole desktop session)

Answer (score 0):

After call

```
export ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_keyStorePath=/Users/Marshall/Documents/eclipse.keystore
```

you should call `source  ~/.bash_profile` to make your setting works at once,or it will work util you open command line again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
task testKeyStorePath << {
    keyStorePath = "$System.env.ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_keyStorePath"
    println "what, " + keyStorePath
    File file = file(keyStorePath)
    println file.isFile()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle has other ways for properties to be set, similarly to how one might with ant (and probably other build tools). Create a `gradle.properties` file in your `$HOME/.gradle` (or `%USERPROFILE%/.gradle`) directory if it does not exist and add the needed properties to it, e.g.:

```
keyStoreFile=/home/<username>/.android/debug.keystore
storealias=androiddebugkey
storepwd=android
```

You can also create the file in the root of the project for anything project-specific.